# How to derive complex data from tables using select statements and operators

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, operators

I have a homework question asking me to 'Find out the PCs which has the highest total cost of software installed on the PCs'.

I have been able to find the max total software cost using the following statement

```
select max(Totalcost)'MaxTotal' from
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' from software
group by tagnum) as Table1
```

However, when I try to select the PC primary key associated with this max(Totalcost) I keep running into syntax errors. How can I go about select the PC primary key associated with this max value?

Any help would be appreciated. I have attached a link to my data below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious I believe I found the answer using the following:

```
select comp from PC where tagnum in
(select tagnum from 
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' from software
group by tagnum) as Table1
where Totalcost = 
(select max(Totalcost)'MaxTotal' 
from
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' 
from software
group by tagnum
) as Table1
))
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways to do this, but have you learnt about `TOP WITH TIES` or window functions? The simplest way to do this might just be `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES PC.comp FROM PC JOIN software ON software.tagnum = PC.tagnum GROUP BY PC.comp ORDER BY SUM(software.softcost) DESC;` since you can avoid all the extraneous joins and multiple aggregations and whatnot.